# How can I access the mapping field directly whilst also having a relationship defined

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-annotations

```
@Entity
@Table(name="sometable_citylocation")
public class CityLocation extends Model implements Serializable {


    private int cityDestinationId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="cityDestinationId", referencedColumnName="destinationId")
    private City city;
```

I have this relationship, where I can get the cities easy by the mapping defined, but I also need to be able to set and alter the cityDestinationId directly because it's supplied to me by external source.

What annotations do I need to be able to do that without losing any functionality(getting cities as object, being able to set/alter/get id from the field/getters/setters)

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'modelDao': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory
>   nl.exit.crunch.dao.AbstractDao.sessionFactory; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path
>   resource [nl/exit/crunch/config/HibernateConfiguration.class]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity:
>   nl.exit.crunch.table.some.destination.CityLocation column:
>   cityDestinationId (should be mapped with insert="false"
>   update="false")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to add insertable and updateable to the object mapping

```
@JoinColumn(name="cityDestinationId",
            insertable=false, 
            updatable=false, 
            referencedColumnName="destinationId"
        )
```

Keep in mind that you cannot use the object to bind/unbind relations. This is not relevant in my case since the foreign key will be supplied from external source. All i care about is getting the object out